# JavaScript - control two-dimensional dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to init a two-dimensional dynamic array in javascript, it don't limit element (maybe) like

```
var dynamic = new Array ();
dynamic[] = new Array ();
```

after i want to add value to special array like

```
dynamic[id].push(2); // id = 3, dynamic[3][0] = 2
...
dynamic[id].push(3); // id = 3, dynamic[3][1] = 3
...
dynamic[id].push(5); // id = 5, dynamic[5][0] = 5
```

it's possible? How can i do that, thanks

Comment: You mean you want to get a new blank array on the index you try to access on `dynamic` automatically if it doesn't exist?

Comment: You can't directly initialize a 2D array. You can however `push()` array elements to your initial array to effectively make it 2D.

Comment: You want to have a 2D array???

Comment: yeah thanks :) like @Ingo Bürk did :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is something like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjWQY/)):

```
var dynamic = [];

dynamic.push = function (id, value) {
    if (!this[id]) {
        this[id] = [];
    }

    this[id].push(value);
}

dynamic.push(3, 2);
dynamic.push(3, 3);
dynamic.push(5, 5);
```

Of course, this can be done even better, but it gets the point across. Personally, I'd write a class for this.

*Edit*: Also, keep in mind that this creates an array with a high potential of having a whole lot of `undefined` values, which needs to be taken care of when reading from it. Also, arrays with holes like this have bad performance (if this will be an issue -- for a few, even a few hundred, values, it won't matter).

Comment: @Ingo Bürk +1 and thanks for ur answer can u pls post how do i retrieve value from this multidimensional array Eg:` I need only id=3 values like (3,2) and (3,3) `

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting `push` might not be the best plan. Adding another method/function would make it simpler to understand. Someone reading `push(1,3)` might assume you're pushing 1 and 3 onto an array instead of 3 into item 1.

```
var dynamic = [];

dynamic.item = function(index) {
    if (!dynamic[index]) {
        dynamic[index] = [];
    }
    return dynamic[index];
}
```

this will allow you to do the following:

`dynamic.item(1).push(1)`

if the "item" does not exist, it is created before its returned, and this allows you to use all array methods on both dimensions of your array. (i beleive)

You could also make this slightly more generic by adding it to the Array prototype which would let you use it on all arrays.

```
Array.prototype.item = function(index) {
    if (!this[index]) {
        this[index] = init;
    }
    return this[index];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, like I said, there are better ways. And I'd still prefer making a class the most. :)